# Pass parameter when form is submitted

Tags: angular, angular9

Using Angular 9 I have the following form:

```
  <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSignUp()">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input id="email" type="text" formControlName="email">
    <button type="submit">SignUp as Professor</button>
    <button type="submit">SignUp as Student</button>
  </form>
```

And the `onSignUp` method is:

```
onSignUp(type: string) {
  // Check type and sign up
}
```

How can I pass the type when the form is submitted?

```
<button type="submit">SignUp as Professor</button> -> type = 'professor'
```

And

```
<button type="submit">SignUp as Student</button> -> type = 'student'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input id="email" type="text" formControlName="email">
    <button type="submit" (click)="handleProfessorClick($event)">SignUp as Professor</button>
    <button type="submit" (click)="handleStudentClick($event)">SignUp as Student</button>
  </form>
```

**UPD**

```
handleStudentClick(event) {
   event.preventDefault()
   ...your logic
}

handleProfessorClick(event) {
   event.preventDefault()
   ...your logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for easy, you should remove (ngSubmit) and add that function into two buttons

In HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="form" >
<label for="email">Email</label>
<input id="email" ng-model="email" type="text" formControlName="email">
<button  ngClick="onSignUp('Professor')">SignUp as Professor</button>
<button  ngClick="onSignUp('Student')">SignUp as Student</button>
```

In Js file

```
onSignUp(type: string) {
    let data = {email: this.email, type: type} 
    this.http.post('http://someurl', JSON.stringify(data ));
 }
```

Comment: Nice. Use the click handler like that: (click)="clickHandler($event)" for Angular2+ though. ng-click is an AngularJS concept.